# SQL ignore results which fail CAST

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Sample WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (QD.New_P11dValue > 0
AND DS.New_purchaseordersenddate IS NOT NULL 
AND DS.New_ActualDate IS NULL 
AND DS.New_PassedToAdmin = 1 
AND ds.New_InStock = 0
)
AND
(
(du.New_AnticipatedDate >= '04/01/2017' AND du.New_AnticipatedDate IS NOT NULL)
OR
(CAST(osu.New_NewValue as date) >= '04/01/2017' AND osu.New_NewValue IS NOT NULL)
)
```

The root cause of my problem is that osu_new_newvalue represents a date but it stored as varchar, I can't change that unfortunately.

I get this error when I run the query

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Is there anyway I could just ignore results which fail the CAST?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Some of the more recent versions have the functions TRY_PARSE, TRY_CONVERT and TRY_CAST that sound of use to you.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Then you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try_convert as below

```
(try_convert(date,osu.New_NewValue) >= '04/01/2017' AND try_convert(date,osu.New_NewValue) IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(try_cast(New_NewValue as date ) >= '04/01/2017' AND try_cast(New_NewValue as date ) IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Comment: Did you test it? For try_cast syntax is: TRY_CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )

Comment: i ediited my answer thanks for correcting my code//@PawelCz